# Modificar estado desde un componente usando React.createElement

Tags: reactjs, undefined

Tengo un gran problema, el objeto this me aparece como indefinido cuando es llamado desde el input text Primer nombre

```
class FormularioDeInscripcion extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {nombre:"",primerApellido:"",segundoApellido:"",correo:"",tipoDocumento:"",documento:""};

        this.actualizarEstado = this.actualizarEstado.bind(this);
    }

    listaTipoDeDocumento = 
        <select>
        <option value="CC">Cédula</option>
        <option value="CE">C.  Extrangería</option>
        </select>;

    primerNombre = React.createElement(
        "input",
        {type:"text",id:"primerNombre",name:"primerNombre",className:"estiloTxt", onChange:this.actualizarEstado}
    );

    segundoNombre = React.createElement(
        "input",
        { type:"text",  name:"segundoNombre", id:"segundoNombre", className:"estiloTxt",onChange:this.oe}
    );



    actualizarEstado(event){
        alert(this.state.nombre);

        if(event.target.id === "primerNombre")
        {
            alert("joeeee");
        }
    }



    render(){
        return(
            <form onSubmit={this.actualizarEstado}>
                {this.primerNombre} Primer Nombre <br></br>
                {this.segundoNombre} Segundo Nombre <br></br>        
                <input type="text" name="primerApellido" id="primerApellido" onChange={this.actualizarEstado}></input> Primer Apellido <br></br>
                <input type="text" name="segundoApellido" id="segundoApellido"></input> Segundo Apellido<br></br>       
                <input type="email" name="correo" id="correo"></input> Correo<br></br>           
                <input type="numeric" name="tarjetaProfesional" id="tarjetaProfesional"></input> Tarjeta Profesional <br></br>    
                {this.listaTipoDeDocumento} Tipo Documento: <br></br>
                <input type="numeric" name="numeroDocumento" id="numeroDocumento"></input> Numero Documento  <br></br> 
                <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
            </form>
        );
    }

}
```

Funciona correctamente desde otros campos que no son creados con React.createElement, pero con estos this queda como indefinido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabo de escribir tu código de la forma en la que yo trabajaría con React, me funciona a la perfección, Ojo que eh quitado el input "submit" para un debuggeo más simple, puedes volver a añadirlo sin problema, si tienes alguna duda, estaré atento!

```
class FormularioDeInscripcion extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        nombre:"",
        primerApellido:"",
        segundoApellido:"",
        correo:"",
        tipoDocumento:"",
        documento:""
    };
}
actualizarEstado = () => {
    console.log('estado: ', this.state)
}
handleInputChange=(event)=>{
    const target = event.target;
    const value =  target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

render(){
    return(
        <form onSubmit={this.actualizarEstado}>
            <input placeholder="primerNombre" name="primerNombre" value={this.state.primerNombre} onChange={this.handleInputChange}  className="form-control" type="text" />
            <input placeholder="segundoNombre" name="segundoNombre" value={this.state.segundoNombre} onChange={this.handleInputChange}  className="form-control" type="text" />
            <input placeholder="primerApellido" name="primerApellido" value={this.state.primerApellido} onChange={this.handleInputChange}  className="form-control" type="text" />
            <input placeholder="segundoApellido" name="segundoApellido" value={this.state.segundoApellido} onChange={this.handleInputChange}  className="form-control" type="text" />
            <input placeholder="correo" name="correo" value={this.state.correo} onChange={this.handleInputChange}  className="form-control" type="email" />
            <input placeholder="tarjetaProfesional" name="tarjetaProfesional" value={this.state.tarjetaProfesional} onChange={this.handleInputChange}  className="form-control" type="numeric" />
            <select onChange={this.handleInputChange} name="tipoDocumento">
                <option value="CC">Cédula</option>
                <option value="CE">C.  Extrangería</option>
            </select>
            <input placeholder="numeroDocumento" name="numeroDocumento" value={this.state.numeroDocumento} onChange={this.handleInputChange}  className="form-control" type="numeric" />
            <input type="button" value="Enviar" onClick={this.actualizarEstado}/>
        </form>
    );
}

}
```

Espero te sirva!!